# ¿Cómo hago para desinstalar una versión antigua de Java?

Tags: java

Tengo una terminal con Windows 10 que me vino preinstalado con una versión antiquísima de Java: **`Java 2 Runtime Environment, SE v1.4.2_04`**, junto con que no la necesito, esta el tema del agujero de seguridad que implica dejarla instalada. He intentado eliminarla de varias formas ya que con la opción de "Agregar Quitar programas" no lo he conseguido:

[image: Herramienta de desinstalación]

He probado sin éxito los siguientes procedimientos:

1. La herramienta oficial para **[desinstalación de Java](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/uninstaller_toolinfo.xml)**
2. **[JavaRa](https://singularlabs.com/software/javara/)**, esta recomendada en múltiples foros y ciertamente automatiza varias de las tareas relacionadas con el mantenimiento de **Java**.
3. **[Wise Program Unninstaller](https://www.wisecleaner.com/wise-progr)**, o cualquiera de las múltiples herramientas de desinstalación.

Comment: Yo habría creado un snapshot sólo por la nostalgia de ver funcionar Java 1.4. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finalmente lo he logrado, rucurrí a una herramienta de Microsoft, que se puede descargar [desde este articulo](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed). Según la documentación:

Arregla problemas del tipo:

- Claves de registro corruptas en sistemas operativos de 64 bits.
- claves de registro corruptos que controlan los datos de actualización.
- Programas nuevos que no pueden instalarse.
- Programas existentes que no pueden desisntalarse.
- Programas  que no pueden desinstalarse mediante "Agregar o quitar programa"

Funciona en:

- Windows 10
- Windows 8.1
- Windows 8
  Windows 7

Comment: Java2, claves de registro ... cuánto tiempo que no leía sobre eso. ¿Empezaste el año en un anticuario?  Saludos :)

Comment: La opción Swartzennegger era borrar los directorios y correr algo como ccleaner para limpiar entradas del registro que apuntaran a directorios inexistentes :P